# Is there any free email service accessible via web service?

Tags: email, services, provider, yahoo-pipes

I need this to be able to send emails from [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) which can only send data to a web service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but there are plenty that can be access over imap, which you should be able to call from yahoo (or failing that, you could write a web service to do that yourself).

Comment: Can you show me any information stating I can use imap in yahoo pipes?